# Citando a un autor

Tags: traducción

¿Cómo cito a un libro escrito por un autor estadounidense o inglés, si ese libro no ha sido traducido al español? Estoy traduciendo del inglés al español.

Answer (score 1):

Honestamente depende del estilo de citado que te pidan (por ejemplo IEEE, APA, MLA, etc.), deberías saberlo y basarte en lo que esté especificado en los documentos de la asociación que regule la correspondiente norma.

A modo de ejemplo en las normas [APA](http://normas-apa.org/citas/como-citar-una-fuente-de-un-idioma-extranjero-y-su-traduccion) lo que se considera válido:

- **Para la cita propiamente dicha**: si la cita es directa presentás la cita original y a continuación mostrás tu propia cita traducida. O bien omitís la cita original pero en ese caso tenés que transformarla a una cita indirecta.
- **Para la lista de referencias**: escribís los datos del libro de la edición o versión exacta de donde sacaste la cita y eso incluye al título en su idioma original, siendo opcional escribir a continuación tu propia traducción del mismo.

En [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referencia_bibliogr%C3%A1fica) hay algunos enlaces a los sitios oficiales de algunas asociaciones que quizás te sirvan para consultar con mayor precisión.

Answer (score -1):

Quizás esto te pueda servir

[image]

**Cuando es una fuente no traducida al idioma español**

[image]

**Cuando es una fuente traducida al idioma español**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Fuente: https://normas-apa.org/citas/como-citar-una-fuente-de-un-idioma-extranjero-y-su-traduccion/

---

**Formato en PDF de la "Guía de Normas APA" 7ª Edición**

https://normas-apa.org/wp-content/uploads/Guia-Normas-APA-7ma-edicion.pdf

Comment: Diego, los nombres no se traducen y poner la pregunta baja el nivel de tu respuesta. :)

Comment: Hola Lambie, imagino que sigues bien. Estoy de acuerdo contigo, "los nombres no se traducen". No se que te ha hecho pensar lo contrarío. En el texto la única referencia es cuando dice, "No traduzca nombres de autores escritos en alfabetos latinos", se entiende que los nombres escritos en árabe, chino, cirílico...se pueden traducir a texto latino, pero no el significado o lo que estos puedan representar en el idioma correspondiente. La otra cuestión tampoco la entendí muy bien, no pongo la pregunta, se trata de una imagen como parte de la respuesta, en la que indico incluso la fuente. Gracias!

Comment: Diego, has dicho: "No se que te ha hecho pensar lo contrarío" Está en tu titulo de parafo: *Es necesario traducir el título? Y el nombre del autor y la organización?*

Comment: Querida Lambie, me iba a volver loco buscando el párrafo. ¿Es necesario traducir el título? ¿Y el nombre del autor y la organización? Esto es una pregunta, entre dos llaves de interrogación y que hace el autor hacia el lector. Por tanto, al ser una pregunta, no es una afirmación. Es como de decir ¿Se puede traducir el título y el nombre del autor? Para posteriormente, dar la respuesta adecuada, que en este caso se encuentra más abajo. "Proporcione una traducción del título entre corchetes" y "No traduzca nombres de autores escritos en alfabetos latinos". Cuídate y disfruta del fin de semana.

Comment: Diego, estoy diciendo que la pregunta en si,  hecha por  quien sea, no tiene ningun sentido. Soy traductora profesional y no acepto la pregunta. El titulo sí, el nombre del autor, no. :)

Comment: Lambie hola de nuevo. No entiendo la "perra" que has cogido con la cuestión. Creo que debe de existir un error en la interpretación, ya que de otro modo lo verías claro como yo. El texto te esta diciendo simplemente que "los nombres no se traducen", salvo que estén en otro alfabeto distinto al latino, como el chino, el árabe, el cirílico....ya que la mayoría de la gente no entendería el significado y la pronunciación de estos caracteres. Por ejemplo, si traduces un libro de 刘震云 , tu no vas mantener estos ideogramas, ya que poca gente sabe como pronunciarlos, sino que dirías "Liu Zhenyun".

Comment: ¿Lo entiendes ahora querida Lambie? :) ¡Cuídate!

Comment: Diego: Es una pregunta invalida. No tiene ningun sentido. Claro, si el nombre es chino o arabe, **hay una transliteración**, que no es por nada traducción.